# How do you overwrite certain date partitions in BigQuery?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table by column `date`.

Let's say I have 3 partitions for the following dates : `2019-04-01, 2019-04-02, 2019-04-03`

At `t+1`, I have an input file containing data for the `2019-04-02, 2019-04-03, 2019-04-04`.

What I want to do is to replace the current partitions for any overlapped dates, and leave unchanged the partition for `2019-04-01, 2019-04-04`.

I've tried using `WRITE_TRUNCATE` but this ends up deleting the whole table on me.  Can someone please assist.

I know partition decorator can be used such as `table$20190404` but how exactly does this work? Is it working in conjunction with `WRITE_TRUNCATE`?  How is it overwriting multiple date partitions if I can only provide the decorator with one date?

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: Yes I figured out a solution

Comment: @staten12 what is your solution?

Comment: @TommyW I set up an airflow scheduled preprocessing job that parses through each date and loads it to said partition using the partition decorator `table_name$20200124`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pre-process your input data for this use-case and exclude the data that you don't want to be updated in the target table. Alternatively, you can load the input data to a new BQ table then use [DML statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data_into_partitioned_tables) to update the target partitioned table